# Intl.js polyfill/shim with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, polyfills

I'm using [React-Intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) with [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) and I need the [Intl](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js) shim to support Safari and IE, but I don't want to load it for browsers that already support the [Intl spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/).

The polyfill is pretty huge (900kb), how can I ensure it only gets loaded in browsers that don't support it already?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to do.

1. Make sure to require `intl/Intl` which loads the core library and not all of the associated countries. This will reduce the size of the library from from around 900kb to around 150kb.
2. Use webpack's `require.ensure` or `require([])` functions to dynamically require Intl.js only when needed. This will create a separate bundle for just the Intl.js file, which will be loaded on an as-needed basis.

**lib/shim.js**

```
// shim for Intl needs to be loaded dynamically
// so we callback when we're done to represent
// some kind of "shimReady" event
module.exports = function(callback) {
    if (!window.Intl) {
        require(['intl/Intl'], function(Intl) {
            window.Intl = Intl;
            callback();
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(callback, 0); // force async
    }
};
```

**app.js**

```
var shimReady = require('lib/shim');
shimReady(startApp);
```

**Note:** You *may* also need access to country-specific information and properties. For my basic needs I didn't actually require this data, but if you do be sure to read the section on Intl.js website [loading locale data](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js#locale-data).

Answer (score 6):

An simple (non-webpack) approach would be to do something like this in your HTML:

```
<script>
 if (!window.Intl) { document.write('<script src="/js/Intl.min.js"><\/script>'); }
</script>
```

Though `document.write` is not considered a best practice, this would provide a blocking approach to solving the problem, resulting in considerably less code in your the application. This solution does not use webpack, but may be a suitable solution for many people in this situation.